# Using Ajax inside another Ajax loaded DIV

Tags: jquery

I have fallen in love with  Ajax  recently so much that I want to do as much with it as possible.

I have a document laid out  as follows:

```
    <ul>
      <li id='myitem'>My item</li>
      <li id='myitem2'>My item 2</li>
      <li id='myitem3'>My item 3</li>
    <ul>

    <div id="loaded_content">
    .....
    ........
    <button id="another_trigger"></button>
        <script></script>
    </div>
```

When the `<li>` element is clicked I load  stuff in the  `loaded_content`  DIV.

Now, the  `loaded_content` DIV has a piece of code that contains  jquery and a button with ID  `another_trigger` .   This is supposed to start an ajax request  once  clicked but it is NOT. I used the  `.live'  method  and it did not work.

Question: Why NOT?

Also: Up to how many levels can it be nested with the  `.live` method?

I hope it makes sense

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: I suggest not including javascript in ajax-loaded content. It can inconsistently be executed in an unexpected order, such as before the elements are appended to the page rather than after.

Comment: Never seen that problem. I use `.load` part of jQuery ajax all the time and load view partials with their own JS no problems at all. I wonder if you could elaborate more on your methodology for load new content and for how you write the view partials

Comment: I think the problem lies in the way u attached the click event to the button. It is never attached because you are attaching before the content is loaded. Paste your javascript so that we can help.

Comment: You should be using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if at all possible (jQuery 1.7 or later). If you can't use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ***[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) should be used in preference to [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)*** (per the jQuery API Docs).